# How to solve "Could not prepare isolate" error?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

```
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                19.2s
E/flutter (23961): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(143)] Could not prepare isolate.
E/flutter (23961): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(385)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter (23961): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(604)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

I do it flutter doctor but there no problem and I do it flutter clean and flutter run also but nothing run

Answer (score 1):

Select `main.dart`, then run. This is an easy mistake to overlook.

Answer (score 1):

1- **Clean project**
2- Select **main.dart** file, Then Run project.....

Simple :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).